# how to manage rounding in angular filter?

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an angular filter that rounds of to 6 decimals. What I cant figure out how to round to 2 decimals when the decimals contain only zeros. So 1.00000 would convert to 1.00.
This is what my filter looks like:

```
app.filter('customCurrency',function ($filter) {
    return function (amount, currencySymbol,fractionSize) {
        var currency = $filter('currency');

        if (amount < 0) {
            return currency(amount, currencySymbol).replace('(', '-').replace(')', '');
        }

        debugger;
        if (fractionSize !== undefined) {
            amount = currency(amount, currencySymbol, fractionSize);
        } else {
            amount = currency(amount, currencySymbol)
        }


        debugger;
        var amounts = amount.split(".");
        var amountHtml ;

         if (amounts[1].length==2 && amounts[1][0]==0 && amounts[1][1]==0)
         {
             amountHtml = amounts[0] + '<span class="decimals">.00</span>';
         }
        else
         {
             amountHtml= amounts[0] + '<span class="decimals">.' + amounts[1] + '</span>';

         }
        return amountHtml;
    };
});
```

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/cGmYcsqwn3huanOeX4g4?p=preview

Comment: I thinki you passing fraction size wrong.Instead of 6 pass 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this will work out for you in the long run as I'm sure there is a better way to go about this, but if you want a quick and dirty fix try this:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/WDXtTHbCdhdDvVGsHE4P?p=preview)

```
app.filter('customCurrency',function ($filter) {

    return function (amount, currencySymbol, fractionSize) {

        var currency = $filter('currency');

        if (amount < 0) {
            return currency(amount, currencySymbol).replace('(', '-').replace(')', '');
        }

        debugger;
        if (fractionSize !== undefined) {
            amount = currency(amount, currencySymbol, fractionSize);
        } else {
            amount = currency(amount, currencySymbol)
        }


        debugger;

        var amounts         = amount.split("."),
            fractionalPart  = amounts[1],
            decimals        = fractionalPart.length,
            zerosFromRight  = countZerosFromRight(fractionalPart);


        if(zerosFromRight > 2){
          return amounts[0] + '<span class="decimals">.00</span>';
        }

        return amounts[0] + '<span class="decimals">.' + amounts[1] + '</span>';
        ///////////////////////////////////

        function countZerosFromRight(str){

          var len   = str.length,
              count = 0;

          while(len--){

            if(str[len] === '0'){
              count++;
              continue;
            }

            break;
          }

          return count
        }


    };
});
```

**EDIT**
Had a rethink and think this way is better:

I've added this test and maybe you don't need this functionality but I think this is a bit more robust.

[DEMO2](http://plnkr.co/edit/GqcPt8ad3zC99Vzf7L0Z?p=preview)

```
it('should only remove the zeros up to the last non-zero number', function() {
    expect($filter('customCurrency')(1.004000, '$', 6)).toEqual('$1<span class="decimals">.004</span>');
    expect($filter('customCurrency')(1.4066000, '$', 6)).toEqual('$1<span class="decimals">.4066</span>');
  });
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('plunker');

app.filter('customCurrency',function ($filter) {

    return function (amount, currencySymbol, fractionSize) {

        var currency = $filter('currency');

        if (amount < 0) {
            return currency(amount, currencySymbol).replace('(', '-').replace(')', '');
        }

        debugger;

        var rounded         = round(amount, fractionSize),
            currencyString  = currency(rounded, currencySymbol, fractionSize),
            amounts         = currencyString.split("."),

            integerPart     = amounts[0],
            fractionalPart  = amounts[1] || false,
            indexLastNonZero = indexLastNonZero(fractionalPart);

        // if only zeros after decimal then remove all but 2
        if(indexLastNonZero === -1){
          return integerPart + '<span class="decimals">.00</span>';
        }

        // if zeros and other numbers after decimal remove all trailing zeros
        if(indexLastNonZero > 1){
          return integerPart + '<span class="decimals">.' + fractionalPart.slice(0, indexLastNonZero + 1) + '</span>';
        }

        return integerPart;
        /////////////////////////////////////////////

        function round(str, decimals){
          var num = +str;

          return num.toFixed(decimals);
        }

        function indexLastNonZero(str){
          var len   = str.length;

          while(len--){

            if(str[len] !== '0'){
              return len;
            }
          }

          return -1;
        }

    };
});
```

Comment: Had another go. Updated second demo and code. Is that what you were aiming for?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
it('if I have 3 zeros or more in decimals only display max of 2 zeros in decimals', function() {
    // using $filter
    expect($filter('customCurrency')(1.000, '$', 2)).toEqual('$1<span class="decimals">.00</span>');
  });
```